# How validate a personal identification number in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp-2.0

I need to validate a field in my form, this field belongs to the personal identification number of my country, this number has 10 digits

Example: card = 1710034065

2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 (coefficient)
1 7 1 0 0 3 4 0 6 (personal identification number)
2 7 2 0 0 3 8 0 12 = 25 (Multiply each digit of the personal number by the
3 coefficient, if the result > 10 add between digits).

add multiplications

The result of the sum

25/10 = 2, Residue 5, divide 10 - residue 5 = 5 (check digit) ** which equals the last number of identity number**

---

Now I need is to implement this logic in the framework and I have no idea how,
I have a example code  in java to get a better idea of what I need to do.

```
    function check_cedula( form )
{
  var cedula = form.cedula.value;
  array = cedula.split( "" );
  num = array.length;
  if ( num == 10 )
  {
    total = 0;
    digito = (array[9]*1);
    for( i=0; i < (num-1); i++ )
    {
      mult = 0;
      if ( ( i%2 ) != 0 ) {
        total = total + ( array[i] * 1 );
      }
      else
      {
        mult = array[i] * 2;
        if ( mult > 9 )
          total = total + ( mult - 9 );
        else
          total = total + mult;
      }
    }
    decena = total / 10;
    decena = Math.floor( decena );
    decena = ( decena + 1 ) * 10;
    final = ( decena - total );
    if ( ( final == 10 && digito == 0 ) || ( final == digito ) ) {
      alert( "La c\xe9dula ES v\xe1lida!!!" );
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      alert( "La c\xe9dula NO es v\xe1lida!!!" );
      return false;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    alert("La c\xe9dula no puede tener menos de 10 d\xedgitos");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your model name is `User` and the field in the database is `card`, you would do the following;

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    /**
     * Validation rules
     */
     public $validate = array(
        'card' => array(
            'validateCard' => array(
                'rule' => array('validateCard'),
                'message' => 'Card does not validate'
            )
        )
    );

    /**
     * Custom validation rule
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCard($field) {
        $cardNumber = $field['card'];

        // Here, perform your logic and return a boolean

    }


}
```

Also, make sure in your view, you're using the FormHelper to output the form inputs and everything should play nice. For example;

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('User.card');
echo $this->Form->end();
```